# Flutter Stateful Widget Constructor That Does Not Include All Members

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, statefulwidget

I am building a Stateful Widget in Flutter, and as such, there is a requirement for all arguments passed in the constructor to be final (since Stateful widgets are marked with the @immutable annotation).

Thing is, I want to have two different constructors for my widget and to exclude some of the members of the Stateful widget, depending on the constructor used. I have to stress, that I do not want these arguments to be optional, but mandatory.

For example,

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
     
  MyWidget.first({this.firstArgument}};

  MyWidget.second({this.secondArgument});

  final int firstArgument;
  final String secondArgument;

  @override
  MyWidget createState() => MyWidgetState();
}
```

When I write this, I get a compiler error, telling me that:

> All final variables must be initialized, but 'firstArgument' isn't.

The same goes for the second member variable.

**How can I overcome this?**

I can't move `firstArgument` and `secondArgument` to the state of MyWidget, since I want them to be initialized in the constructor(s) and also because they should not be changed.
I can't mark them as not final since then I will get a compiler warning and also break the Stateful widget paradigm.

**Is there a different approach I should use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thing is, I want to have two different constructors for my widget and to exclude some of the members of the Stateful widget, depending on the constructor used. I have to stress, that I do not want these arguments to be optional, but mandatory.

If you don't want them to be optional, you need to mark them as required:

```dart
  MyWidget.first({required this.firstArgument}};

  MyWidget.second({required this.secondArgument});
```

(If you don't have null-safety enabled, you will instead need to use the weaker `@required` annotation from `package:meta`.)

My understanding is that you want `firstArgument` and `secondArgument` to be required for `MyWidget.first` and `MyWidget.second` respectively but that they are not intended to be required *together* (that is, only one should be set).

You could fix this by explicitly initializing both values in the constructors:

```dart
  MyWidget.first({required this.firstArgument}} : secondArgument = null;
  MyWidget.second({required this.secondArgument}): firstArgument = null;
```

If you have null-safety enabled, you also would need to make your members nullable:

```dart
  final int? firstArgument;
  final String? secondArgument;
```

Comment: @jamesdiin - thanks for the detailed answer. Could you briefly explain or point to a place that does so the constructor syntax you provided and it's meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **factory** constructors would help?

```dart
    class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
         
      MyWidget._({this.firstArgument, this.secondArgument}};
    
      factory MyWidget.first({@required int first})=>MyWidget._(firstArgument: first, );
      factory MyWidget.second({@required String second})=>MyWidget._(secondArgument: second, );
      final int firstArgument;
      final String secondArgument;
    
      @override
      MyWidget createState() => MyWidgetState();
    }
```

This way, you'll only be able to build this widget using these constructors (since the class constructor is private) and when you call MyWidget.first the value for *secondArgument* for the widget will be null, and the same applies when you use MyWidget.second with *firstArgument*

Comment: You also could use [redirecting constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#redirecting-constructors) instead of `factory` constructors.